# Provisioning database schemas in ruby

Tags: ruby, database, provisioning

I'm looking for a database agnostic way to create new schemas. Something like

```
postgres_uri = "postgres://username:password@hostname/database"
mysql_uri = "mysql://username:password@hostname/database"

[postgres_uri, mysql_uri].each do |db|
  connection = DB.connect(db_uri)
  connection.create_schema("xyz")
end
```

Bonus marks for something that will work easily with the connection active_record establishes in rails.

Comment: Is using [datamapper](www.datamapper.org) an option?

Comment: datamapper does have a great api for manipulating schemas. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have any way to create/delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is somehow having two active_record "instances" and running activerecord migrations on each.  Sequel allows for the same thing, and even allows for string instance names.

Comment: I've ended up using sequel with separate sqls for each database. I was hoping to avoid having to write code for each db but I couldn't find anything that would do it out of the box and the sql is pretty simple.